# How can I open a local file with a local program through my browser?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

On my webpage, I have placed a link to a local file (e.g. "text.docx" on my local HD). I would like to double click on this link, and have a third party software which is installed locally on my PC (e.g. Microsoft Word) open it.

I would like to be able to do this with Firefox and Google Chrome. Obviously, I am a newbie to web programming.. can somebody show me the way? I have looked around and had the impression that I need to write and add an extension, maybe?

Thanks for your time. Jakob

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you're trying to do? What would you like to be able to do?

Comment: I would like to be able to click on the link (on my webpage) to a file which resides on my PC. As a result, I would then like this file to be opened automatically with a program which is also installed on my PC. The program used would be according to the file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to execute code locally, using Firefox, by adding an extension which used the XPCOM interface. One such extension was "commandrun", and may be found here: https://github.com/aabeling/commandrun .

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible if you know either the absolute path to the file or the relative path from whatever working directory your browser runs from. You the create a link with

```
href="file://relative/path/to/file/text.docx"
```

or

```
href="file:///absolute/path/to/file/text.docx"
```

and any modern browser will query the system database for the mimetype of the file depending on its extension, thus prompting to open the correct application.

**EDIT**

I inawarently introduced a unixism in the previous code: Distinction bewteen absolute and realtive paths as above works well on current *nix desktops, but in Windows an absolute path will most likely look like

```
href="file://C:/drive/absolute/path/to/test.docx"
```

Mind the 2 (not 3) slashes a the beginning, and the forward (not backward) slashes.

Comment: Thanks.. .. I have a program which I wrote myself, I am sure no mimetype assignment exists, how can I set this program to be called using this input file?

Comment: If you register your file suffix ( "allways open *.myp with myprogram.exe" ) with the system, it will just work.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was fine with the nixing. I stick to Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't link to local files from a website. If you upload it to where your files are, you could then be able to download it.